# Problem on integration: $\int\frac{\log_{\ e}[\sec x]}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Well, Today I am very confused over a integral problem and I tried 
wolfram and many websites they did not help me.
Compute:
$$\int\frac{\log_{\ e}[\sec x]}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ 
this I have to solve to find integral of arcsinx and tanx

The Whole Equation:
$$ \int \sin^{-1}x \tan x=\sin^{-1}x\log_{\ e}|\sec x|-\int\frac{\log_{\ e}[\sec x]}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

Can Any one give solution fully yo Me and Thanks

Comment: Did you invent this?

Comment: i am begineer to this if its wrong sorry.

Comment: Even alpha isn't able to do this..

Comment: why even computer cant solve it?

Comment: There are some users here known for being able to solve integrals like this that Wolfram and Mathematica can't do, just give them some time.

Comment: It may not be possible to provide a closed form answer either. Lots of innocent looking indefinite integrals have no closed form.

Comment: so there is no solution for this intergral?

Comment: @Nikunj This means nothing. There are lots of things that Alpha cannot do, but we can.

Comment: @Balla `Can't solve an integral` in this context means that there is no known elementary or special function whose derivative is the integrand.

Comment: What is $\sin^{-1}x$ in your original integral? Is it $\arcsin x$ or $\csc x$?